# Select Query for these tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have two tables items and item_details.
[image: Table items]

[image: Table item_details]

To show the items in the feeds page I use the below JOIN QUERY.

```
SELECT i.item_id,i.time,id.text,id.photo FROM items i LEFT JOIN item_details id ON i.item_id=id.item_id
```

but, it returns multiple rows of same item id. The only work around I find is first select the items table only, then select the item_detail table while looping in PHP. I feel that's not a best practice and may effect the performance.

Kindly suggest a better method to select the items.

Comment: If you aren't supposed to have a one-to-many relationship in the table how come you have one? Or on the other hand, if there is supposed to be a one to many, how come you are trying to stop it showing up in your code?

Comment: It is how it should work as per your design. Do you want to have only one row?

Comment: yes onerow with one image and one text.... I will show all other when go to the detail page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

You are joining with `item_details` which has 3 records with same `item_id`. So the result **will** have more records for that `item_id`.

**Solution:**

I think this is what you after:

```
SELECT i.item_id,i.time,MAX(id.text) as text,MAX(id.photo) as photo
FROM items i LEFT JOIN 
     item_details id ON i.item_id=id.item_id
GROUP BY i.item_id,i.time
```

Sample result:

```
item_id time    text                            photo
---------------------------------------------------------------------
2       87213   (null)                          (null)
4       2029    another text row for item id 4  a photo for item id 4
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c48d5/2)

**NB:** This method will not work as expected if you have multiple records with same `item_id` having different values for `text` and `photo` columns.